# Using a C# class library as a COM+ server application

Tags: c#, .net, interop, com-interop, com+

I created a .NET class library in C# and exposed it to COM. It works fine as an in-proc COM server. However I want to use it as an out-proc COM server to have it in a separate process.

To do so I try to create a COM+ application. I created an empty COM+ application and added the classes implemented in the class library into it. When I call CoCreateInstance() to instantiate a class implemented in the library, the COM+ surrogate process encounters an access violation and terminates (crash dump folows).

Are there any special steps needed to be taken to create a class library that can be used as an out-proc COM server under COM+?

The COM+ surrogate process crashes with the following crash dump:

Exception: C0000005
Address: 0x000C1618

Call Stack:
! + 0xC1618
mscorwks!Ordinal79 + 0xE41C
mscorwks!Ordinal79 + 0xE4AD
mscorwks!CoInitializeEE + 0x563F
mscorwks!CoInitializeEE + 0x5672
mscorwks!CoInitializeEE + 0x57F1
mscorwks!CoInitializeCor + 0x210E
mscorwks!CoInitializeCor + 0x48D
mscorwks!Ordinal79 + 0x16D2
mscorwks!ReleaseFusionInterfaces + 0x20B28
COMSVCS! + 0xC29A2
COMSVCS! + 0xC2BDA
COMSVCS!CoCreateStdTrustable + 0xCB10
ole32!CoMarshalInterface + 0x2642
ole32!CoInstall + 0x673
ole32!CoQueryAuthenticationServices + 0x1F44
ole32!CoQueryAuthenticationServices + 0x2862
ole32!CoWaitForMultipleHandles + 0xC267
ole32!CoQueryClientBlanket + 0x16CE
ole32!CoCreateObjectInContext + 0xC8E
ole32!CoInstall + 0x87A
ole32!CoWaitForMultipleHandles + 0x10479
ole32!CoMarshalInterface + 0x2808
ole32!CoGetTreatAsClass + 0xBE7
ole32!CoGetTreatAsClass + 0xB9E
ole32!CoMarshalInterface + 0x28F2
ole32!CoMarshalInterface + 0x2642
COMSVCS!CoCreateStdTrustable + 0x106A4
ole32!CoMarshalInterface + 0x2642
ole32!CoPopServiceDomain + 0x14FE
RPCRT4!CheckVerificationTrailer + 0x70
RPCRT4!NdrStubCall2 + 0x215
RPCRT4!CStdStubBuffer_Invoke + 0x82
ole32!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile + 0xFC92
ole32!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile + 0xFC3C
ole32!CoRevokeClassObject + 0xA3E
ole32!CoRevokeClassObject + 0x963
ole32!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile + 0xF872
ole32!WdtpInterfacePointer_UserMarshal + 0x80E
ole32!StgGetIFillLockBytesOnFile + 0xF792
RPCRT4!NdrGetTypeFlags + 0x1C9
RPCRT4!NdrGetTypeFlags + 0x12E
RPCRT4!NdrGetTypeFlags + 0x5A
RPCRT4!CreateStubFromTypeInfo + 0x2D7
RPCRT4!CreateStubFromTypeInfo + 0x318
RPCRT4!NdrConformantArrayFree + 0x2CB
RPCRT4!NdrConformantArrayFree + 0x20F
RPCRT4!I_RpcBCacheFree + 0x61C
RPCRT4!I_RpcBCacheFree + 0x43E
RPCRT4!I_RpcBCacheFree + 0x604
kernel32!GetModuleFileNameA + 0x1B4

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps going through the ServicedComponent example in this answer will help:

[Create Out-Of-Process COM in C#/.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446417/create-out-of-process-com-in-c-net)

Comment: Will I be able to also use the same class library as an in-proc COM server if I make it a serviced component?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can declare the activation type at run time.  You will want to look through this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtk4bdsx(VS.80).aspx and this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/afha61xz(VS.80).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at .Net Remoting instead.

Comment: Will this allow me to use the C# class library from unmanaged C++ code?