# Create COM object in out proc server

Tags: com

I have a COM dll implementation with set of methods from multiple interfaces. I want to test my COM implementation to check whether my COM implementation is working when its created from out-proc.

How to create COM object in out-proc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways to accomplish this, but I think the easiest way is to register our DLL (COM server) under [COM+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685978%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Also, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446417/create-out-of-process-com-in-c-net).