# .Net 6 project had to set platform to x86 to load c++ DLL , Will this affect the application since it cannot run as x64 because of other references

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I have a .Net 6 application that had to set platform to x86 to load c++ DLL. The application references many of other .Net 6 class library projects, along with Serilog, EF, and other nuget packages.
Will having to set the application platform to x86 cause issues with the nuget packages used and other .Net 6 class libraries it references at runtime?
Not sure what do because expertise is not in the field of the problem

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on which bitness modes are supported by other dependencies. The problem will only be if you will have dependency with x64-only native library used.

- If all your dependencies are pure managed (.net) then everything will be fine.
- If there is a dependency that uses some native/unmanaged dlls and it package contains the code to handle the x86/x64 modes correctly (e.g. to load different dlls for each mode), then all will be fine.
- If there is a dependency that uses some native/unmanaged dlls and the only x86 version of the dll exists, then again all will be fine.
- Finally, if there is a dependency that uses some native/unmanaged dlls and the only **x64** version of the dll exists, then that dependency will fail to load the dll and will probably break the application.

And even with x64-only dependencies in some particular case you still can make all of this together by offloading the dependencies of different bitnesses into the separate process, as described here [64bit C# .Net Wrapper for 32bit C# .Net DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74349860/64bit-c-sharp-net-wrapper-for-32bit-c-sharp-net-dll/74370522#74370522)

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I will log this answer for future reference. I