# Can I create a COM server with just C# 4.0?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, com-interop, out-of-process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do I need to do to implement an “out of proc” COM server in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-implement-an-out-of-proc-com-server-in-c)

Hello,

I don't know much about COM or C++, so perhaps this is a silly question:

Without resorting C++/ATL wrapper program, can I make an out-of-process C#/.net 4.0 application that's callable via COM from traditional COM clients?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can. you can do either way. use tlbimp to import type library and tlbexp to export your type library. Make sure your assebly had a strong name and mark your objects as comVisibile or not. MSDN is the better source